# Coloring a bootstrap menu and making it active

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a web-page using bootstrap whose header looks more or less like w3schools. I am attaching the image file which shows both of them for convenience.[image]

As you can see in the yellow bar, I have the look and also the entry turns black when I highlight it. W3Schools however turns the entry to green if clicked. So, if I am viewing HTML turorial it displays the HTML menu entry in green.  How would once achieve this using bootstrap?.

I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom_styles.css"></script>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"> <!-- PavanD: navbar-static-top helps in removing the rounded navbar.-->
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#5F5F5F;"> <!--505050 can also be considered -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id=headerEntries class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONCEPTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C++</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JAVA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ORACLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">REACH US</a></li>          
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

I came up with this css.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff; /* PavanD: This is the color of the elements when they load. */
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #000000; /* PavanD: When you click the top menu items, they have to be rendered in black.*/
    color: #ffffff; /* PavanD: This is the color of the elements when they are clicked. We want it to be white so this.*/
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
  background-color: #8AC007; /* PavanD: When you click the top menu items, they have to be rendered in black.*/
    color: #ffffff; /* PavanD: This is the color of the elements when they are clicked. We want it to be white so this.*/
}
```

But it is only showing the green color once I press something. For example if I am at home page and if I click ABOUT page, it momentarily shows me the green color and reverts back to the grey color.
I am new to web programming and I was thinking if this is being done using java script[?] but not sure. Any inputs would help greatly.

The following seems to be the css for w3 page. It is using its own w3.css.
    .topnav a.active {
        background-color: #8AC007;
        color: #FFF;
    }

For the w3schools page, I can see that the link which I have clicked would have its status changed to active. More specifically speaking, if I click HTML course, I can see

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
<div style="float:left;width:50%;overflow:hidden;height:44px">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="topnav-localicons w3-hide-large w3-left" onclick="open_menu()" title="Menu">☰</a>
<a href="/default.asp" class="topnav-icons fa fa-home w3-left" title="Home"></a>
<a href="/html/default.asp" class="**active**" title="HTML Tutorial">HTML</a>
<a href="/css/default.asp" class="w3-hide-small" title="CSS Tutorial">CSS</a>
<a href="/js/default.asp" class="w3-hide-small" title="JavaScript Tutorial">JAVASCRIPT</a>
```

How should one do this?. Is this javascript?.

Thanks a lot.

Pavan.

EDIT: A little jquery did the magic.

```
    <script>     
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var pathname = this.location.pathname;
    if ( pathname.indexOf('about') > -1 ) 
    {
        $( "#about_home" ).addClass("active");
    }
    else if ( pathname.indexOf('concepts_explore') > -1 ) 
    {
        $( "#concepts_home" ).addClass("active");
    }
    else if ( pathname.indexOf('c_explore') > -1 ) 
    {
        $( "#c_home" ).addClass("active");
    }
    else if ( pathname.indexOf('cpp_explore') > -1 ) 
    {
        $( "#cpp_home" ).addClass("active");
    }
    else if ( pathname.indexOf('java') > -1 ) 
    {
        $( "#java_home" ).addClass("active");
    }
    else if ( pathname.indexOf('ds_explore') > -1 ) 
    {
        $( "#ds_home" ).addClass("active");
    }
    else if ( pathname.indexOf('sql_explore') > -1 ) 
    {
        $( "#sql_home" ).addClass("active");
    }
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Please put the HTML and CSS related to the menu bar. Or create a JSFiddle with your codes. Would be easy to give you a solution.

Comment: @XahedKamal: Added to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the CSS use for an active state: See working example.

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #8AC007;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  /* PavanD: This is the color of the elements when they load. */
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #000000;
  /* PavanD: When you click the top menu items, they have to be rendered in black.*/
  color: #ffffff;
  /* PavanD: This is the color of the elements when they are clicked. We want it to be white so this.*/
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
  background-color: #8AC007;
  color: #ffffff;
}
/***Link Background and Color Active State***/

.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #8AC007;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <!-- PavanD: navbar-static-top helps in removing the rounded navbar.-->
  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#5F5F5F;">
    <!--505050 can also be considered -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id=headerEntries class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONCEPTS</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">C++</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">JAVA</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">ORACLE</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">REACH US</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I am seeing the green highlight on Home page irrespective of what I click. I think this is because of the fact that we have the active class marked on the home menu item. So what should I be doing to make this dynamic?. Like the class="active" getting added to whatever I click in the menu bar.

Comment: That ultimately has to do with how you're implementing your application. Since the example is just static html that doesn't change to a new page it wouldn't change. If your only using this on a static site you add the active class to that pages link like in the example.

Comment: So, if I have 10 possible entries [ 10 pages ] should I have 10 different versions where each version would have one of the 10 pages colored in green?.

Comment: If you have 10 static pages then each page would have the active class applied to that pages navbar link. Otherwise you would use a serverside solution (generally).

Comment: Curious, can I not use javascript/jquery and do some innerHTML modification to the appropriate <li> based on my selection?.

Comment: I have updated my question with a jQuery snippet that did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is done in css and in html.
Firstly you need to set the class name of the element that is active at a certain page.

For example if you have a HTML-page link in your navbar, on the HTML-page you add the classname "active" for the  element:

```
<a class="active" href="http://www.w3schools.com">HTML</a>
```

Then you add the css rule for it to the color you want:

```
.nav a.active 
{
     background-color: #8AC007; 
     color: #FFF; 
}
```

So for example if you have two html pages: home.html and about.html
your navbar could look like this for the home page:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="home.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
</ul>
```

and like this for the about page:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" class="active">about</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now if you want hover effects also, thats another css rule: a:hover that you can add to your css file.

Comment: If I have 10 menu entries and I want this functionality to be enabled for all of them, then I should somehow be able to add the class="active" part when I click on a particular menu entry. Can you please let me know how this is achieved?. Do we use Java script there?.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this --

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <!-- PavanD: navbar-static-top helps in removing the rounded navbar.-->
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#5F5F5F;">
        <!--505050 can also be considered -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id=headerEntries class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">CONCEPTS</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">C</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">C++</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">JAVA</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">ORACLE</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">FAQs</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">REACH US</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Little CSS change required to get color like w3schools

```
.nav li.active > a{
    background-color: #8AC007 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Script to keep the Background color (or the a tag as active) after an 'a' tag clicked-

```
$('.nav a').click(function () {
   $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active'); // Disable/Remove this line if you want to keep green whatever the user has selected/clicked

   $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kamal. I have it working for a single entry in the menu bar. My question is if I have 10 menu entries and I want this functionality [ displaying in green when clicked ] to be enabled for all of them, then I should somehow be able to add the class="active" part when I click on a particular menu entry. Can you please let me know how this is achieved?. Do we use Java script there?.

Comment: "10 menu entries", did you mean 9 more menu like this one? and you want to add the same effect on all menu?

Comment: So, in this menu bar, I have C, C++, Java and so on right. I want to show in Green whatever the user has selected in that menu nav bar.

Comment: $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');  --- Disable/Remove this line if you want to keep green whatever the user has selected/clicked

Comment: That almost did it Kamal. However, when I click the last entry which is about, I get highlighting of Home instead of About. Do you have any inputs on it.

Comment: That should not be happening. Can you share link of the live page/site where you are applying it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91292/discussion-between-pavan-and-xahed-kamal).